# How to use Open Type Font (OTF) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have added the font in `pubspec.yaml` Any `True Type Font` works just fine. But, when I add `Open Type Font` it doesn't work.

Here is my how I added font in `pubspec.yaml`

```
  fonts:
    - family: Kufyan
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Kufyan.otf
```

Comment: can you add your `pubspec.yaml` code here?

Comment: Check this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: Be it `ttf` or `otf` it should work proprly though, can you link or provide that fonts that you're using.

Answer (score 23):

✔️ Officially works since 24 feb of 2021

Proofs

1. Since this [commit](https://github.com/flutter/website/commit/7811b5a702cbf27cf3c61735426770b7e545e761#diff-a50d485f952f4e196538cd5ccd5e1d1edb33d61b4b4ee63d739fbde18c77b9fc) (GitHub)
   [image]
2. Current docs state look [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts) (Flutter docs)
   [image]

Answer (score 21):

The flutter recent version **v1.12.13** does not support the open type font(otf) directly. You have to convert the otf to true type font(ttf) somehow. You can use this third-party website to [covert the font to ttf](https://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-ttf) before using it in your project. You can refer to the guide on [how to use custom fonts in flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts) for more information.

Flutter matches the font family based on the metadata in the font itself. So defining `family: Kufyan` is not required in `pubspec.yml`

---

**Note**: OTF is now officially supported, see [supported font types](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts)

Comment: I'm using flutter v1.16.2 and otf font works completely fine

Comment: How about .ttc font? It does not seem to work with mine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455895/convert-or-extract-ttc-font-to-ttf-how-to This might help you

Comment: I'm using flutter 2.2.3 and oft fonts are usable, but you can't "turn on" advanced otf features

Answer (score 6):

Just tested with Futter 1.20 and looks like OTF fonts work as expected. I can't seem to find anything in the docs about what type of fonts Flutter supports.

Answer (score 4):

The Flutter engine matches fonts within a family based on the metadata in the font itself.

```
(We should remove the style descriptors in pubspec.yaml now that they are obsolete).
```

> Declaring these fonts as different families in pubspec.yaml will work
>   around this.

Example can be seen [here](https://github.com/squanchy-dev/squanchy-flutter/blob/master/pubspec.yaml) 
which you have done.

> **But otf is may not be supported. it can be because of google fonts.**

If its still not working then...

> There is a trick you can use which is to convert otf to ttf via a
>   third party i.e. [convertio](https://convertio.co/otf-ttf/) etc.

Then you can use it as a normal font.

> - Import the font files.
> - Declare the font in the pubspec.
> - Set a font as the default.
> - Use a font in a specific widget.

Answer (score 2):

The Flutter engine matches fonts within a family based on the metadata in the font itself, not the style descriptors declared in the pubspec.yaml manifest.
(We should remove the style descriptors in pubspec.yaml now that they are obsolete).

The Edmondsans regular, medium, and bold fonts contain metadata declaring their weights as 400, 410, and 420 respectively. However, the Flutter text subsystem only supports font weight buckets representing even multiples of 100 (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontWeight-class.html). So all three of these fonts are mapped to FontWeight.w400, and the font style matcher can not choose between these fonts based on weight.

Declaring these fonts as different families in pubspec.yaml will work around this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert otf font file in ttf font file using this platform. https://convertio.co/otf-ttf/
2. Import the font files.
3. Declare the font in the pubspec.
4. Set a font as the default.
5. Use a font in a specific widget.

Here is the example and steps to use custom font.
https://www.xam-consulting.com/blog/adding-custom-fonts-in-flutter-application